# Принудительное использование new в конструкторах JS

Tags: javascript

Есть такой шаблон, который предотвращает проблемы, которые могут возникнуть, если в *JavaScript* вызвать конструктор без ключевого слова **new**:

```js
function Waffle() {
  if (!(this instanceof Waffle)) {
    return new Waffle();
  }

  this.tastes = "yummy"; // Почему это свойство запишется в объект?
                         // Ведь мы же уже возвратили объект из конструктора
}

Waffle.prototype.wantAnother = true;

var test = Waffle();
console.log(test.wantAnother);
console.log(test.tastes);
```

Я не понимаю, почему свойство **tastes** записывается в экземпляры класса **Waffle**. Ведь мы еще до его присвоения возвратили объект из конструктора(при вызове конструктора без *new*)
Примечание. Пример взят из книги *"Стоян Стефанов. Javascript. Шаблоны"*

Answer (score 3):

Алгоритм следующий:

1. `var test = Waffle();` (вызов без new вернёт нам new Waffle, то есть функция-конструктор вызовется, сработает условие);
2. так как функция вызвалась (она вызвала сама себя в условии) уже с ключевым словом `new`, условие не сработает и в наш экземпляр запишется `this.tastes`

То есть, первый раз условие сработало и вызвалась функция, а потом уже записалось свойство. В этом и есть суть данного примера

Answer (score 1):

При вызове функции без ключевого слова `new` значение `this` может варьироваться.

В данном случае, если `this` не является создаваемым объектом, конструктор запускается вручную

```
new Waffle();
```

и возвращается созданный объект, а уже в этом запуске происходит инициализация поля `tastes` - так как `this` теперь указывает на создаваемый объект.